# Calling specific service on web api

Tags: java, json

I have a web API running with a service called Authorize.

Authorize takes 1 parameter (called ) and returns a different key.

I'm going to call this from a Java application. I've done

```
public static void main(String[] args0)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try{

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:50481");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("Authorize={\"auth\":\"123456\"}");
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);            
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

        System.out.println(json);

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    finally{ 

    }
}
```

The problem is, that the `System.out.println(json);` only returns an empty object: `{}`

Does that mean that there is a problem in the service itself, or that it does not hit a valid method on the API?

Comment: Do you have access to the code for the Authorize service? It looks like it is returning an empty JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

As `{}` is a valid (empty) json and there aren't any exception you run into it looks pretty much like your service returns a response with an empty json object.